# How are homing pigeons' "homes" changed?

Tags: ornithology

Last night I was watching the David Attenborough minidocumentary on animal navigation, and it talked about the homing pigeons used in the two World Wars.

Apparently they were donated by UK pigeon fanciers for the war effort.

However, when used as war messengers, obviously they had to "home" back to HQ, not their original UK roost.

How do you "reprogram" the pigeons to use a new home? I assume that pigeon fanciers have to do this all the time if they move house?

(I couldn't find a pigeon SE site so hope this is on-topic here!)

Comment: My brother captured a bunch of ordinary pigeons at one building where they had been nesting, then kept them in a second building a couple of miles away for about a month, where they nested and were well fed.  He gave them freedom after that month, and most of them kept coming back to the second building.  I suspect that knowing it was a good home and knowing their flock mates might be found there were factors in their "reprogramming".